# Replace index.php with htaccess rewrite

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm using wordpress and it run will `index.php` on root. How do I make one of my folder, says its name is `script` to run instead of `index.php` using htaccess rewrite? Redirecting is one of the way but that's not what I want, because it can't retain the URL. I want example.com to serve the content of example.com/script without changing the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DirectoryIndex

```
DirectoryIndex script
```

This will internally map your homepage to /script

another solution is mod-rewrite

Put the following rule above your existing rules after the RewriteEngine directive :

```
RewriteRule ^$ /script [L]
```

Comment: will this effect my wordpress? means those blog post, like example.com/2016/5/12/sample-post/

Comment: No, this won't effect your main index.php or wp posts.

Comment: Doesn't work, it will redirect me to example.com/script, I want example.com to load content of example.com/script without changing the url.

Comment: Try the second solution, this works fine on my server.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me. I will follow the url. this is my wordpress .htaccess file 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere not with the rules.

Comment: I don't think so. What do u mean by else where?